# How to set the min value to zero on this Wordpress slider

Tags: php, wordpress

I wish to set the default value for a slider on a WordPress real estate website to be zero, not the lowest value of the cheapest property. How can I edit the code below to do this? I have attached an image to show how it currently is, where it shows 1200 euro I wish that to be zero euro. I have attempted to play around with it myself on a staging site with not much luck. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awJS7.png)
Thanks

```
<?php

if( $min == $max )
    $min = 0;

?>
<?php if( $model ): ?>
    <stm-field-range inline-template
                     data-v-bind_key="generateRandomId()"
                     data-v-model='<?php echo esc_attr( $model ); ?>'
                     data-v-bind_callback_change='<?php echo esc_attr( $callback_change ); ?>'
                     prefix='<?php echo esc_attr( $prefix ); ?>'
                     suffix='<?php echo esc_attr( $suffix ); ?>'
                     min='<?php echo esc_attr( $min ); ?>'
                     max='<?php echo esc_attr( $max ); ?>'>
        <div class="inventory-range-filter">
            <div class="container">
                <?php if( isset( $field[ 'label' ] ) ) {
                    $field_range_before = apply_filters( "stm-field-range-before", [ 'model' => $model, 'prefix' => $prefix, 'field' => $field ] );
                    echo ( !is_array( $field_range_before ) ) ? $field_range_before : "";
                } ?>

                <div class="filter-range-fields">
                    <input type="text" data-v-model="from" data-v-on_change="setValue(from+';'+to)"
                           data-v-on_keyup="setValue(from+';'+to)">
                    <input type="text" data-v-model="to" data-v-on_change="setValue(from+';'+to)"
                           data-v-on_keyup="setValue(from+';'+to)">
                </div>

                <vue-range-slider data-v-bind_min="min"
                                  data-v-bind_max="max"
                                  data-v-bind_from="cloneFrom"
                                  data-v-bind_to="cloneTo"
                                  type="double"
                                  data-v-bind_prefix="prefix"
                                  data-v-bind_postfix="suffix"
                                  data-v-on_callback='updateValue'
                                  data-v-bind_key="generateRandomId()">
                </vue-range-slider>

                <?php if( isset( $field[ 'label' ] ) ) {
                    $field_range_after = apply_filters( "stm-field-range-after", [ 'model' => $model, 'prefix' => $prefix, 'field' => $field ] );
                    echo ( !is_array( $field_range_after ) ) ? $field_range_after : "";
                } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </stm-field-range>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above case, `$min` will only be 0 if `$min` and `$max` are equal.

I believe the solution is to just remove that `if` altogether.

Try this out:

```
<?php
#if ($min == $max)
$min = 0;
?>
```

If that works, just remove the `if`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, that creates a critical error removing that

Comment: What's the error? Can you include it in the post please?

Comment: sorry, it was an input error by myself. it does not bring up an error now but it does not change anything, it remains with the lowest, cheapest property still rather than a 0.

Comment: Try it with a value of 1, maybe 0 is special so it gets ignored. If a 1 doesn't do it, can you include the rendered HTML from the site that represents that code up top? Maybe something there will jump out

Comment: I changed it to 1, that did not work either, the HTML does not display the figure either, the HTML looks like this: <div class="filter-range-fields"><input type="text"> <input type="text"></div>

Comment: I notice that if I drag the slider right then left it does now show as 1 or 0 rather than 1200 so that is progress. It just needs to display 0 once loaded rather than 1200 (which is the cheapest property type

Comment: Sorry, i can't provide any more help ... :-/   I want to delete the answer since it's no good but I'll leave it up for now in case someone else can help out. Good luck